# R: Generate plot axis break labels with superscripts programmatically

Tags: r, plot, expression, axis, superscript

I would like to make tick labels with superscripts as in mylabels in the following example. However, I don't want to hand code them, I want them to go up to 3^LEVELS, where LEVELS is a constant

```
library(ggplot2)

LEVELS = 4

mylabels = c(
  expression(paste(3^4,"= 81")),
  expression(paste(3^3,"= 27")),
  expression(paste(3^2,"= 9")),
  expression(paste(3^1,"= 3")),
  expression(paste(3^0,"= 1")))
mylabels
length(mylabels)


df=data.frame(x=runif(40),y=(runif(40)*10)%%5)
p = ggplot(df,aes(x,y))  + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:LEVELS, labels = mylabels)
p
```

The hard coded version works perfectly. But I can't seem to get it programmatically. The following:

```
mylabels=c(paste("expression(paste(3^",LEVELS:0,'," = ',3^(LEVELS:0),'"))',sep=""))
```

doesn't properly evaluate in the chart (e.g., it writes the word 'expression', etc. in the label). It creates:

```
[1] "expression(paste(3^4,\" = 81\"))" "expression(paste(3^3,\" = 27\"))" "expression(paste(3^2,\" = 9\"))" 
[4] "expression(paste(3^1,\" = 3\"))"  "expression(paste(3^0,\" = 1\"))"
```

and what I want is:

```
expression(paste(3^4, "= 81"), paste(3^3, "= 27"), paste(3^2, 
"= 9"), paste(3^1, "= 3"), paste(3^0, "= 1"))
```

Have messed about with collapse, noquote, eval, sprintf, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build the expression vector as a character vector first, and then parse it using [`parse()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/parse.html), which returns an expression vector correspondent to the input character vector. Building the character vector is best done with [`sprintf()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html):

```
mylabels <- parse(text=sprintf('paste(3^%d,\' = %d\')',LEVELS:0,3^(LEVELS:0)));
mylabels;
## expression(paste(3^4,' = 81'), paste(3^3,' = 27'), paste(3^2,' = 9'),
##     paste(3^1,' = 3'), paste(3^0,' = 1'))
```

[image: plot]

---

Other tips:

**1:** When providing sample code that depends on random number generation, please call [`set.seed()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html) before generating any randomness.

**2:** The [`expression()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/expression.html) function is variadic, and returns an expression vector whose elements correspond to the input arguments. Hence you can replace

```
c(
    expression(paste(3^4,"= 81")),
    expression(paste(3^3,"= 27")),
    expression(paste(3^2,"= 9")),
    expression(paste(3^1,"= 3")),
    expression(paste(3^0,"= 1"))
)
```

with

```
expression(
    paste(3^4,"= 81"),
    paste(3^3,"= 27"),
    paste(3^2,"= 9"),
    paste(3^1,"= 3"),
    paste(3^0,"= 1")
)
```

**3:** Avoid redundant calls to `c()`. You can replace

```
c(paste("expression(paste(3^",LEVELS:0,'," = ',3^(LEVELS:0),'"))',sep=""))
```

with

```
paste("expression(paste(3^",LEVELS:0,'," = ',3^(LEVELS:0),'"))',sep="")
```

Comment: plus1 well done .. I was wasting too much time on this. (seems you can simplify it `mylabels <- parse(text=sprintf('3^%d == %d', LEVELS:0, 3^(LEVELS:0)))`, but I dont know if that will come back and bite

Comment: @user20650 Excellent point, your simplification works here. The only caveat is that if the piece of the label to the right of the `3^%d` was not valid R syntax, then it wouldn't work, because `parse()` would not be able to parse it into a valid R parse tree. But since it is valid syntax in this case, it works.